# I get a 404 when I try to load paginated objects

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

After successfully developing a method to paginate my Next JS app, I get a 404 when I try to load the detailed objects after I load paginated data.

I'll show you below.

1. Here are the first objects that get called on initial loading.

[image]

2. When I click through, I get the detailed page correctly, as shown below.

[image]

3. But when I proceed to click the load more button as shown below.

[image]

4. I am able to load the next 12 data from the backend as shown below.

[image]

5. The problems comes when I click through to see the objects that comes through after clicking the load more button, I get a 404 error.

[image]

6. Here is my code results.tsx where I render the blog list page

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  colors,
  useMediaQuery,
  FormControl,
  OutlinedInput,
  InputAdornment,
  Button,
  Avatar,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Divider,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import { Icon, Image } from 'components/atoms';
import { CardProduct, Section, SectionAlternate } from 'components/organisms';
import { formatDate } from '../../../../../utils';
import { LoadMore } from 'components/molecules';

import { useState } from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  link: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  pagePaddingTop: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(5),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(5),
    },
  },
  sectionAlternate: {
    '& .section-alternate__content': {
      padding: theme.spacing(3),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(3),
      [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(5),
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing(5),
      },
    },
  },
  searchInputContainer: {
    background: theme.palette.alternate.main,
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    boxShadow: '0 4px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11)',
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(1),
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      border: '0 !important',
    },
    '& .MuiInputAdornment-positionStart': {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-adornedStart': {
      paddingLeft: 0,
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
      padding: 0,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      padding: theme.spacing(1),
    },
  },
  searchButton: {
    maxHeight: 45,
    minWidth: 135,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      minWidth: 'auto',
    },
  },
  cardProduct: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(1),
    '& .card-product__content': {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    },
  },
  image: {
    objectFit: 'cover',
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(0, 0, 20, 0),
  },
  blogContent: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    height: '100%',
  },
  list: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatarContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  avatar: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  divider: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2, 0),
  },
  button: {
    minWidth: '100%',
    maxWidth: '100%',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      minWidth: 420,
    },
  },
  answerCount: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1 / 2, 1),
    borderRadius: theme.spacing(1),
    background: theme.palette.secondary.light,
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 300,
  },
}));

const Result = ({
  data,
  className,
  posts,
  pageInfo,
  ...rest
}: ViewComponentProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [allPosts, setallPosts] = useState(posts);
  console.log(allPosts)

  const classes = useStyles();

  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('md'), {
    defaultMatches: true,
  });

  const BlogMediaContent = (props: ImageProps) => {
    return (
      <Image
        {...props}
        src={props?.node?.featuredImage?.node?.mediaItemUrl}
        className={classes.image}
        lazyProps={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      />
    );
  };

  const BlogContent = (props: any) => (
    <div className={classes.blogContent}>
      <Typography variant="h6" color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
        {props.title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body1" color="textSecondary">
        {props.subtitle}
      </Typography>
      <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
      <Divider className={classes.divider} />
      <div className={classes.list}>
        <div className={classes.avatarContainer}>
          <Avatar {...props.author.photo} className={classes.avatar} />
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textPrimary">
            {props.author}
          </Typography>
        </div>
        <Typography variant="overline" color="textSecondary">
          {props.date}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className={className} {...rest}>
      <SectionAlternate className={classes.sectionAlternate}>
        <Grid container spacing={isMd ? 4 : 2}>
          {allPosts.map((post: any, index: number) => (
            <Grid
              className={classes.link}
              item
              xs={12}
              sm={6}
              md={4}
              key={index}
              data-aos="fade-up"
            >
              <Link legacyBehavior href={`/blog/${post.node.slug}`}>
                <CardProduct
                  withShadow
                  liftUp
                  className={classes.cardProduct}
                  mediaContent={
                    <BlogMediaContent {...post} alt={post.node.title} />
                  }
                  cardContent={
                    <BlogContent
                      title={post.node.title}
                      // subtitle={item.subtitle}
                      author={'copyandpost'}
                      date={formatDate(post.node.date)}
                    />
                  }
                />
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          ))}
          {/* <Grid item xs={12} container justify="center">
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="large"
              className={classes.button}
            >
              Load more
            </Button>
          </Grid> */}
        </Grid>
      </SectionAlternate>
      <Section paddingSmall display="flex" flexCenter>
        <LoadMore
          allPosts={allPosts}
          setallPosts={setallPosts}
          pageInfo={pageInfo}
        />
      </Section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Result;
```

7. Here is my Loadmore.tsx where I rendered my pagination logic

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { getBlogPosts } from '../../../../lib/api';

const LoadMore = ({ allPosts, setallPosts, pageInfo }) => {
  const handleOnclick = async event => {
    const morePosts = await getBlogPosts(pageInfo.endCursor);

    let updatedPosts = {
      pageInfo: {},
      nodes: [],
    };
    updatedPosts.pageInfo = morePosts.pageInfo;

    allPosts.map(node => {
      updatedPosts.nodes.push(node);
    });

    morePosts.posts.edges.map(node => {
      updatedPosts.nodes.push(node);
    });

    setallPosts(updatedPosts.nodes);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onClick={handleOnclick}
        variant="contained"
        size="large"
        color="primary"
      >
        Load More
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoadMore;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using `AppRoute`? or `PageRoute`?

Comment: I used the page route its a next JS app

Comment: Please leave a minimal re-production of your issue on Github, Gitlab or some Code Sandbox websites. It's so tough to track the issue.

Comment: Its company code,  I cant do that?

Comment: Dear @UdemezueJohn, All of us are working on our company projects. I told you, please leave a `minimal re-production` of your issue, not the exact project codes. I meant to create a bare project by using whatever you are building for your project and simulating the issue. Then let me have a look.

Comment: okay, Ill see what I can do

Comment: Have you left a reproduction of the issue?

Comment: no, I haven't, I can't do it, I don't know how to, its a very huge project.

Comment: Create a new project. Simulate that part you had that issue, then try to simulate the issue. Otherwise no one can't help you.

Comment: Okay, let me see what I can do .

Answer (score 0):

If initial items load and route correctly, the issue shouldn't be the API or data itself. I'm doubting if the way you updated the state (direct state mutation) caused the problem. Maybe you could try this way to update the state and see if it works:

```js
const handleOnclick = async event => {

  const morePosts = await getBlogPosts(pageInfo.endCursor);

  setallPosts(prevPosts => {
    const newPosts = morePosts.posts.edges;
    return [...prevPosts, ...newPosts];
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks , but it did not work